# WPF to powershell errors

Tags: wpf, forms, powershell

I'm pretty new on powershell and noob on GUI.
I try to make a GUI working with powershell
Windows 7 with powershell V2

Here is my xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="558.138" Width="474.668">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,46">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="335*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="37*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="Adobe READER" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,215,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="98" Margin="6,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454">
        <Image x:Name="logo_europe_jpg" Margin="177,0,0,9" Source="logo_europe.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Border>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox_Copy" Content="PDF Creator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,236,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox_Copy1" Content="VPN Client" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,306,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="EUROPE TECHNOLOGIES STORE" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox_Copy2" Content="WinSCP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox_Copy3" Content="Google Chrome" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox_Copy4" Content="Mozilla Firefox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,151,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,12,0,-22" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,113,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="404"><Run Text="Sélectionn"/><Run Text="ez"/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="les applications à installer et appuyez sur OK"/></TextBlock>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Annuler" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="263,12,0,-22" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="22"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Suggestion de programmes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Envoyer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Row="2"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

i changed x:name by name
i deleted x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"

here's the error

```
    Exception lors de l'appel de « Load » avec « 1 » argument(s) : « XmlNamespace, Assembly ou ClrNamespace absent de l'ins
truction Mapping. Ligne '0' position '0'. »
Au niveau de \STORE\EUROPE_ALEX_STORE.ps1 : 43 Caractère : 40
+ $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load <<<< ($reader)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Vous ne pouvez pas appeler de méthode sur une expression ayant la valeur Null.
Au niveau de \STORE\EUROPE_ALEX_STORE.ps1 : 46 Caractère : 17
+ $Form.ShowDialog <<<< () | out-null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ShowDialog:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

i deleted four lines:
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"

mc:Ignorable="d"

Another error :

```
    Exception lors de l'appel de « Load » avec « 1 » argument(s) : « Compilation obligatoire du fichier XAML qui spécifie l
es événements. Ligne '0' position '0'. »
Au niveau de \STORE\EUROPE_ALEX_STORE.ps1 : 39 Caractère : 40
+ $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load <<<< ($reader)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

    Vous ne pouvez pas appeler de méthode sur une expression ayant la valeur Null.
    Au niveau de \STORE\EUROPE_ALEX_STORE.ps1 : 42 Caractère : 17
    + $Form.ShowDialog <<<< () | out-null
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ShowDialog:String) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

there are no events on my buttons, i just want to display my form first.

here is the entire powershell script

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
Add-Type -AssemblyName WindowsBase

[xml]$xaml = @’
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="EUROPE STORE" Height="560" Width="480">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,46">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="335*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="37*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox" Content="Adobe READER" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,215,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked"/>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="98" Margin="6,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454">
            <Image Name="logo_europe_jpg" Margin="177,0,0,9" Source="logo_europe.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Border>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox_Copy" Content="PDF Creator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,236,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked"/>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox_Copy1" Content="VPN Client" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,306,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="EUROPE TECHNOLOGIES STORE" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310"/>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox_Copy2" Content="WinSCP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox_Copy3" Content="Google Chrome" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox_Copy4" Content="Mozilla Firefox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,151,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
        <Button Name="button" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,12,0,-22" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,113,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="404"><Run Text="Sélectionn"/><Run Text="ez"/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="les applications à installer et appuyez sur OK"/></TextBlock>
        <Button Name="button1" Content="Annuler" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="263,12,0,-22" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="22"/>
        <TextBox Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Suggestion de programmes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button Name="button2" Content="Envoyer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Row="2"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

#Read XAML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

#Show Form
$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null 

# SIG # Begin signature block
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made some changes for you in your XAML code. You can't specify Event actions in the XAML like you would with C# using PowerShell. I saw errors with Click (for buttons) and Check (for Checkbox) events that were in the XAML code. These should be handled after you have loaded the XAML.

Note my comments in the code example regarding **loading the controls** and **handling the events**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
Add-Type -AssemblyName WindowsBase

[xml]$xaml = @’
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="EUROPE STORE" Height="560" Width="480">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,46">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="335*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="37*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox" Content="Adobe READER" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,215,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="98" Margin="6,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454">
            <Image Name="logo_europe_jpg" Margin="177,0,0,9" Source="logo_europe.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Border>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox_Copy" Content="PDF Creator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,236,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox_Copy1" Content="VPN Client" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,306,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="EUROPE TECHNOLOGIES STORE" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310"/>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox_Copy2" Content="WinSCP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox_Copy3" Content="Google Chrome" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox_Copy4" Content="Mozilla Firefox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,151,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,3.382"/>
        <Button Name="button" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,12,0,-22" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,113,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="404"><Run Text="Sélectionn"/><Run Text="ez"/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="les applications à installer et appuyez sur OK"/></TextBlock>
        <Button Name="button1" Content="Annuler" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="263,12,0,-22" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="22"/>
        <TextBox Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Suggestion de programmes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button Name="button2" Content="Envoyer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Row="2"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

#load the controls here
$button = $Form.FindName('button')

#Handle the event stuff here
$button.Add_Click({
    Write-Verbose 'Button was clicked!' -Verbose
})

#Show Form
$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```